# WinJS Adding related searches from a website?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

Is it possible to get related searches from a website (like Google) while the user is typing in a search box?

I want something like Google's "I'm feeling lucky" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Google search API: [LINK](https://developers.google.com/web-search/)

or Bing seach API : [LINK](http://www.bing.com/developers/)